# Using WorkItemTrackingHttpClient through a proxy to get DevOps work items

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops-rest-api

Using .Net Core 3.1, I am trying to retrieve workitems via a WIQL query. The sample code I am using is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/work-item-quickstart?view=azure-devops

The problem I am having is using this through our network proxy. The code works fine on a machine without a proxy but fails with
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com." when using the proxy.

I can establish a connection directly to Devops and do simple REST queries using a HttpClient with a handler as follows:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
  [code here]
}
```

I can't find a way to set up the HttpClientHandler to be part of the WorkItemTrackingHttpClient connection.

I am new to C# and the .Net world, so this may be a trivial question.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Does exception occurs after 30 seconds?  In some cases the defaults are set to a proxy that is not needed.  Soimple solution is set proxy to null : client.Proxy = null;

Comment: No, the exception occurs immediately.

Comment: Are you logged into you company private network?  If you are using DefaultCredentials and in the private network I do not know why you would need the handler.  The network should recognize the default credentials.  I would make sure you are logged into the corporate network.

Comment: I am logged into the network. Everything else works apart from this code. The direct HTTPClient example I also found on the MS website required the "handler.DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;" adding before it worked so it definitely seems to be proxy related.

Comment: When it worked previously were you using Core 3.1?  Did anything else change?  Can you go back to what worked and see if it still works?  It may not be the proxy and I just want to make sure something else isn't the issue.  There may be other API's that need to be updated with Core 3.1.  See authentication on following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1

Comment: It only worked previously on a different PC (home PC) not behind the proxy. Both machines are set up identically using VS Code, .Net Core 3.1 etc. Both are very recent installs with no other packages downloaded.

Comment: The roles on the network have to be setup properly. You should talk to your MIS people.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started